# Are non-constant, analytic functions topologically conjugate to $z\rightarrow z^m$ when $f'(0)=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Given a non-constant, analytic function $f$ of the form

$f(z) = z^m + a_{m+1} z^{m+1} + a_{m+2} z^{m+2} + \cdots$

one can show that $f$ can be written in the form

$f(z) = f_1(z)^m$

where $f_1$ is a local analytic isomorphism (proof can be found in most complex analysis textbooks).  This simplifies the local picture (at $z=0$) of $f$ a little bit since instead of a big power series, we can think of $f$ as first an isomorphism, followed by the nice function $z\rightarrow z^m$.

But I'm curious if you can go a little further and find, for the above $f$ and the map $p_m(z)=z^m$, a local topological conjugacy between the two maps, where the conjugacy is analytic.  That is, can one find an analytic map $h$, with $h(0)=0$ and locally isomorphic at $0$ s.t.

$f = h^{-1}\circ p_m\circ h$

on a small ball around $0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do one better. There is always an injective holomorphic map $g$ such that $f\circ g^{-1}=z^m$, where $m=v_0(f)$. This is often times called the "local normal form" theorem. It has applications in many places of complex analysis. A proof can be found here: http://mathnt.mat.jhu.edu/zelditch/Teaching/F09RS/DrorRS.pdf

Comment: Isn't the $g$ you gave the same as $f_1$ above?  If $f(z) = f_1(z)^m$, then $f\circ f_1^{-1} = z^m$, right?